# Can you prove that this function is bijective?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $T(x,y)=(5x+\sin(y),5y+\arctan(x))$. Prove T is a bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

This is a problem from a test for undergraduate students, i don't know where to start.

EDIT: What i know is that if $f:A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1(A)$ where $A$ is open and if $x_0\in A$ is such that $J_f(x_0)$ is not zero then $f$ is locally invertible near $x_0$.

Notice that with $J_f$ i meant the Jacobian of the function $f$

Comment: what you know about maps, bijective maps ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you haven't done so already I highly recommend the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site. Also, take a look at our suggestions for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). You'll find there a sublink for [how to avoid "I don't know where to start" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), which I highly recommend if you wish to avoid down votes and close votes.

Comment: @GCab i Know the condition for a function to be locally invertible

Comment: ..and which  is ? add to your post what you know

Comment: @GCab sorry, i edited. If there's a result that can help me and that i don't know, tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prove that for any two real numbers $a$ and $b$, there exist a unique point $(x,y)$ such that
$$5x + \sin(y)=a\\5y+\arctan(x)=b$$
Solving for $y$ as a function of $x$ and subtituting in the first equation, we get:
$$5x + \sin\left(b-\frac{\arctan(x)}{5}\right)=a$$
Letting $f(x)$ be the expression on the left, we have $$f'(x) = 5 - \frac{1}{5(1+x^2)}\cos\left(b-\frac{\arctan(x)}{5}\right)$$
Clearly $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$, so f is a one-to-one function. Furthermore,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty \text{ and } \lim_{x\rightarrow{-\infty}}f(x)=-\infty$$
So $f$ is also surjective. Hence there exists a unique $x$ such that $f(x)=a$, and since $y$ is uniquely determined by $x$, this proves the existence and uniqueness of $(x,y)$.